# Rails: uninitialized constant just happen on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I have a class that I put inside `lib/network`:

```
module NetworkApi
  class NetworkProxy
  end
end
```

Then in another class, I referenced this class:

```
  network_proxy = ::NetworkApi::NetworkProxy.new(params)
```

Everything runs normally on my development environment, but when I deploy to the server, I get an error at the above line with the message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant NetworkApi::NetworkProxy
```

I don't know why this strange error happens. Please tell me why.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that [Rails 5 disables autoloading after booting the app in production](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html).

From the linked blog post:

> In the rare situation where our application still needs autoloading in the production environment, we can enable it by setting up `enable_dependency_loading` to `true` as follows:
>
> ```
> # config/application.rb 
>
> config.enable_dependency_loading = true
> config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`
> ```