# rails_api_auth overriding Oauth2Controller is throwing error on production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication

I am building a small management application where I wanted to add a precheck for a user to login into the system. I am using [rails_api_auth](https://github.com/simplabs/rails_api_auth) gem. I was trying to override its *Oauth2Controller*, it is working on dev environment but getting error on production environment.

Error:

```
app/controllers/session_controller.rb:19:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RailsApiAuth::Oauth2Controller (NameError)
```

Overriden controller:

```
class SessionController < RailsApiAuth::Oauth2Controller
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user[:admin]
       # do something
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Is there anything which I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Could this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560187/3251051) be the solution?

As the original author stated, Rails 5 disables autoloading after booting the app in production.

As stated, change the following inside application config file ->

```
    # config/application.rb

    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```